# How to detect BlackBerry Model in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, blackberry

Is there a way to detect BlackBerry Model in asp.net,

I have made some search on the net but i have not find a solution

I try to use userAgent information , but it seem's that the format change from one version to another,

for exemple for BlackBerry 8900 , Request.UserAgent = "BlackBerry8900/5.0.0.681 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/-1"

for BlackBerry Torche : Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.141 Mobile Safari/534.1+"

Thank's in advance for your Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have your answer.  To detect the various models, just parse the user agent field.

Note that a lot of times just the simple fact that the format changed is indicative of a different model.  This is called "finger printing".

Comment: I have find my answer here http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862?IID=DEVSF30

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/142590/How-to-detect-BlackBerry-Model-in-ASP-NET.aspx